# What do the fields in the libata device probe line in dmesg mean?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, sata, dmesg, libata

When the kernel boots, it prints out lines like this for each SATA device:

```
[    0.919450] ata2.00: ATA-8: ST2000DM001-1CH164, CC24, max UDMA/133
[    0.919487] ata2.00: 3907029168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
```

What do those fields mean?

Comment: Posting this here because I got to go through kernel sources to figure out what `AA` meant. Google only gave unanswered forum posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ata2.00: ATA-8: ST2000DM001-1CH164, CC24, max UDMA/133
```

`ATA-8` is the version (SATA II). `ST2000DM001-1CH164` is the device model number. `CC24` is the device firmware version. `UDMA/133` would be the speed, if this were a PATA device instead of SATA.

```
ata2.00: 3907029168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
```

Sector count should be obvious. Multi is the number of sectors that can be read/written in a single request. `LBA48` means its using 48-bit logical block addressing (as opposed to 28-bit LBA, or the ancient cylinder-head-sector method). `NCQ` means it supports native command queuing. For the `depth`, if the host supports a greater-or-equal depth compared to the device, you'll only see one number—the device depth. Here, it's host depth (`31`), device depth (`32`), in that order. `AA` means the device is using SATA II auto-activate mode.